# NGINX + memcached, location not found

Tags: nginx, memcached

I want to configure nginx to read directly from `memcached` by key "match_1" for example.

This is my `server` configuration

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location /get_match {

            set             $memcached_key "match_$arg_match";
            memcached_pass  192.168.3.54:11211;

    }

}
```

However, when I try to access http://example.com:8080/get_match?match=1 I get a `404 Not Found`.

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT**:

I changed `location /get_match` to `location @get_match` and I no longer get a 404, but a blank page.

---

**FIXED**:

I changed to `location = /get_match`. It worked.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. If you were able to answer your own question, you should post it as an answer. This is not a forum, and answers can be missed if they are part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only changed `location /get_match` to `location = /get_match`. It worked.

I don't get why, though. I thought that the `=` only shows the EXACT location and stops the parser from searching for other possible matches for the given location. Any comments would be appreciated.